# Is there a canonical, if not core, Gnu Privacy Guard CPAN module?

Tags: perl, cpan, gnupg

I'm looking for the right GPG Perl module to use for a small project. I see there are numerous competing modules providing almost identical functionality, but some have a slew of unaddressed bugs, haven't received an update in half a decade, etc. Is there a GPG module one should *always* use, or do I just need to bite the bullet and assess which is the best for my needs and whose bugs will have the least impact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used Ruby's GPGME module to do some pretty cool stuff with GPG.  GPGME is a C library, and various people have ported it to other scripting languages.  I'd try out the following one and see if it works for you.  It should function as if you're writing a native GPGME-linked C program.

[Crypt::GpgME](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt%3a%3aGpgME)

Cheers!

Comment: Since you've posted, there has been 3 more releases of Crypt::GpgME.  You should link to the permalink: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-GpgME/

Comment: @Leolo, that's the permalink to the distribution's page.  The permalink equivalent to the original link is http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt::GpgME

Comment: @cjm I find the dist link more useful then the perldoc link.  YMMV.

Comment: @Leolo, I generally prefer to go straight to the documentation.  It's not that big a deal, as each page links directly to the other page, but the link from the docs to the dist is a bit easier to find.